# How to convert varchar to float in SQL Server ? I get an error

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert data from temporary table (`AmazonSales_temp`) to my main table (`AmazonSales`). The temporary table has all columns as type `varchar`. The main table has some `float` and `varchar` values. I am trying to insert using a stored procedure.

When I execute the stored procedure, I get an error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure usp_LoadAmazonSales, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 2]
> Error converting data type varchar to float

I tried every possible way. Any idea how to fix this? Need help.

```
INSERT INTO AmazonSales
    SELECT
        [ProductTitle],
        CAST(Revenue AS FLOAT),
        CAST(RevenueTotal AS FLOAT),
        CAST(RevenuePriorPeriod AS FLOAT),
        CAST(RevenueLastYear AS FLOAT)
    FROM 
        AmazonSales_temp
```

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax suggests SQL Server.  You can get rid of the error using `TRY_CAST()`:

```
insert into AmazonSales
    SELECT [ProductTitle],
           TRY_CAST(Revenue AS FLOAT),
           TRY_CAST(RevenueTotal AS FLOAT),
           TRY_CAST(RevenuePriorPeriod AS FLOAT),
           TRY_CAST(RevenueLastYear AS FLOAT)    
    FROM  AmazonSales_temp;
```

That said, this only masks the error.  It inserts `NULL` values.  You need to find the problems.  For that, run queries like this to find the offending records:

```
SELET a.*
FROM AmazonSales_temp a
WHERE TRY_CAST(Revenue AS FLOAT) IS NULL AND Revenue IS NOT NULL;
```

I would also advise you not to use `FLOAT` for monetary values.  These are much, much better represented as `DECIMAL`/`NUMERIC`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This WORKS!